# How big is the download for an upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much data do I need to download to upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48081/how-much-data-do-i-need-to-download-to-upgrade-to-a-new-version-of-ubuntu)

I would like to know the download size when updating from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04.  I have limited bandwidth, and would like to plan when the download happens.